# Virtual List - Searchbar error

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, cordova, framework7

estoy con un error respecto al buscador de mi virtual list de mi App jsF7-Cordova.

Extrae todos los items que necesito desde localstorage (es un arrayJson con alimentos), la virtual list ‘funciona’ pero a la hora de realizar la búsqueda la misma busca en los elementos renderizados o ya ‘cargados’. Realizo scroll y si genera nuevo contenido me permite realizar busqueda con esos nuevos elementos cargados, contrario si no realizo el scroll jamas busco los elementos que poseo. Por lo que es un buscador que funciona pero no busca de la forma que deberia buscar. Para este codigo revise la sig doc:

https://v3.framework7.io/docs/virtual-list
https://v3.framework7.io/docs/swipeout

Estaría necesitando que la búsqueda sea para toda el arrayJson que tengo. ¿Alguien tuvo un problema similar? o ¿qué error estaría cometiendo?

Adjunto codigo:

JS:

```
    // Virtual List: Nutricion
function initializeVirtualListNutrition() {
  debb("[ui_alimentos | VirtualList] initializeVirtualListNutrition()");

  // Alimentos:
  const alimentosString = localStorage.getItem('getSup_alimentos');
  const alimentos = JSON.parse(alimentosString);
  const totalAlimentos = alimentos.length;
  const items = []; // ArrayAlimentos
  for (let i = 0; i < totalAlimentos; i++) { // genera el nombre y calorías del alimento
    let alimentoID = i; // Mover la declaración aquí
    items.push({
      title: alimentos[i].nombre_producto,
      kcal: alimentos[i].calorias,
      subtitle: 'Vg.: ' + yesOrNo(alimentos[i].apto_vegano) + ' | Vt.: ' + yesOrNo(alimentos[i].apto_vegetariano) + ' | Sin Gluten: ' + yesOrNo(alimentos[i].apto_celiaco),
      idAlimentoIcon: alimentoID // Usar alimentoID en lugar de i
    });
  }
  let virtualList = app.virtualList.create({
    // List Element
    el: '.virtual-list-nutrition',
    // Pass array with items
    items: items,
    // Custom search function for searchbar
    searchbar: {
      el: '.searchbar', // Selector del elemento de búsqueda
      searchContainer: '.virtual-list-nutrition', // Selector del contenedor de la Virtual List
      searchIn: '.item-title', // Selector del elemento en el que se realizará la búsqueda
    },
    // List item render
    renderItem(item) {
      return `
        <li class="swipeout">
          <div class="item-content swipeout-content">
            <div class="item-media centerContain">
              <img src="./media/iconFood${item.title}.svg" width="18" alt="icono de Comida"/>
            </div>
            <div class="item-inner">
              <div class="item-title-row">
                <div class="item-title">${item.title}</div>
                <div class="item-title">${item.kcal} kcal</div>
              </div>
              <div class="item-text">${item.subtitle}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="swipeout-actions-left">
            <a href="#" class="color-blue swipeout-overswipe alert-reply" id='detallesAlimento' data-name="${item.title}" data-id="${item.title}">Detalles</a>
          </div>
          <div class="swipeout-actions-right">
            <a href="#" class="color-green open-more-actions" data-name="${item.title}" data-id="${item.idAlimentoIcon}">Agregar</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      `;
    },
    // Item height
    height: app.theme === 'ios' ? 63 : 73,
  });
}
```

// Ejecucion:

```
$$(document).on('page:init', '.page[data-name="alimentos"]', function (e) { // Inicializador:
  debb("<View> ================================= | ================================= [alimentos]");

  // Asignar el evento click a los elementos .open-more-actions: muestra momentos del dia para registrar alimento [boton agregar comida]
  $$(document).on('click', '.open-more-actions', function () {
    let button = $$(this);
    let swipeout = button.parents('.swipeout');
    let name = swipeout.find('.swipeout-actions-right a.open-more-actions')[0].textContent.trim();
    debb('Botón de acción seleccionado:', name);

    alimentoID = button.data('id');
    nombreAlimento = button.data('name');
    debb('[ALIMENTOS seleccionados]' + alimentoID + ' | ' + nombreAlimento);
    moreActions.open();
  });

  $$(document).on('click', '#detallesAlimento', function () {
    const alimentoID = $$(this).data('id');
    localStorage.setItem('alimentoSeleccionado', alimentoID);
    debb(alimentoID);
    app.views.main.router.navigate('/detalleAlimento/');
  });

  initializeVirtualListNutrition(); // Lista virtual de alimentos.
}); // ; añadido recientemente
```

HTML:

```
<div class="page" data-name="alimentos">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner sliding">
      <a class="back"><img src="./media/iconBack.svg" alt=""></a>
      <div class="title textoResaltado">Alimentos</div>
      <div class="subnavbar">
        <form data-search-container=".virtual-list-nutrition" 
        data-search-item="li" data-search-in=".item-title" 
        class="searchbar searchbar-init">
          <div class="searchbar-inner">
              <div class="searchbar-input-wrap">
                <input type="search" placeholder="Search"/>
                <i class="searchbar-icon"></i>
                <span class="input-clear-button"></span>
              </div>
              <span class="searchbar-disable-button">Cancel</span>
          </div>
       </form>              
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="searchbar-backdrop"></div>

  <!-- Contenido de la pagina: -->
  <div class="page-content">
    <div class="searchbar-backdrop"></div>
    <div class="list simple-list searchbar-not-found">
      <ul>
        <li>Ups, lo que buscas no se encuentra!</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="card list virtual-list media-list searchbar-found">
      <div class="card-content" id="fabri">
        <ul class="list media-list virtual-list-nutrition"></ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Fin de contenido de la pagina.-->
</div> <!-- Fin de HTML -->
```